# How to pass two lambda functions using a single template parameter in C++

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, types, functional-programming

I am writing a program that calculates numerically the value of the voigt distribution. However I'm encountering a problem when I try to pass gauss' and lorentz's functions using a single class template parameter `F`, even though they are of the same type.

When I use two templates arguments, say `F1` and `F2`, it works like a charm. But g++ throws an error whenever there is just one. Passing the lambdas immediately as `splot`'s (convolution's) parameters doesn't help.

```cpp
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

#define MIN -10.
#define MAX 10.
#define EPS 0.01

template <typename T, class F> T trapezoid(F f, T a, T b, T eps) {
    T result = T(0);
    while (a <= b) {
        result += f(a);
        a += eps;
    }
    result -= (f(a) + f(b)) / T(2);
    return result * eps;
}

template <class F>
double splot(F g, F l, double x, double sigma, double gamma) {

    auto s = [g, l, x, sigma, gamma](double x_prime)->double {
        return g(x_prime, sigma) * l(x - x_prime, gamma);
    };

    return trapezoid(s, MIN, MAX, EPS);
}

int main (void) {
    double x = 0., sigma = 1.5, gamma = 0.1;

    auto gauss = [](double x, double sigma)->double {
        return exp(-1*x*x / (2*sigma*sigma)) / (sigma * sqrt(2*M_PI));
    };

    auto lorentz = [](double x, double gamma)->double {
        return gamma / (M_PI*(x*x + gamma*gamma));
    };

    cout << "x: " << x << endl << "V(x): " <<
     splot(gauss, lorentz, x, sigma, gamma) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26187711/two-lambdas-passed-to-template-function-makes-type-deduction-of-parameter-ambigu) would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### What's the problem ?

If I understand well your question,  when you define `splot()`, using a different template parameter for each lambda passed, it compiles perfectly:

```
template <class F1, class F2>
double splot(F1 g, F2 l, double x, double sigma, double gamma) {
    ...
}
```

But both lambdas that you use have the same signature (same argument types and same return type) so you expect them to be of the same type, and the following definition of `splot()` to compile as well:

```
template <class F>
double splot(F g, F l, double x, double sigma, double gamma) {
    ...
}
```

But it doesn't compile, and the compiler makes it even confusing with [an error message](https://ideone.com/D4ibKr) that  suggests that both lambdas have a different type, whereas the displayed type name indicates the same type:

```
note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘F’ (‘main()::<lambda(double, double)>’ and ‘main()::<lambda(double, double)>’)
```

#### Why is there a problem ?

The compiler is right despite the misleading error message.  There is an error in the type deduction with `F`:  the C++ standard states in `[expr.prim.lambda.closure]/1` that:

> The **type of a lambda-expression** (which is also the type of the closure
>   object) **is a unique**, unnamed non-union class type, called the closure
>   type, whose properties are described below.

So every lambda has a different type, even if they share the same signature.

Comment: Thanks, I was misled, because our teacher gave us this as homework and he wrote the function prototype with just one template class.

Answer (score 4):

I'd advise you to use a `std::function<>` as shown below:

```
typedef std::function<double(double,double)> func;

func gauss = [](double x, double sigma)->double {
    return exp(-1*x*x / (2*sigma*sigma)) / (sigma * sqrt(2*M_PI));
};

func lorentz = [](double x, double gamma)->double {
    return gamma / (M_PI*(x*x + gamma*gamma));
};

cout << "x: " << x << endl << "V(x): " <<
 splot(gauss, lorentz, x, sigma, gamma) << endl;`
```

as @Christophe pointed out, lambda will have different types, when this on the other hand, ensures that you keep the same type for all your methods.

Comment: Nice one ! I'd just suggest the more modern alternative to typedef:  `using func = std::function<double(double,double)>;`

Comment: yup! I always forget about this alternative, gotta get used to it :)

Answer (score 2):

It's basically because they're not of the same type.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main (void) {
  auto gauss = [](double x, double sigma)->double {
                 return exp(-1*x*x / (2*sigma*sigma)) / (sigma * sqrt(2*M_PI));
               };

  auto lorentz = [](double x, double gamma)->double {
                   return gamma / (M_PI*(x*x + gamma*gamma));
                 };

  cout << typeid(gauss).name() << endl;
  cout << typeid(lorentz).name() << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Look at how it gives diferent ids for each function. It's barely explained in [this link](https://www.quora.com/C++-How-to-pass-a-lambda-function-as-a-parameter-of-another-function). Then I guess you'll have to stick with doing:

```
template <class F, class G>
double splot(F g, G l, double x, double sigma, double gamma) {

    auto s = [g, l, x, sigma, gamma](double x_prime)->double {
        return g(x_prime, sigma) * l(x - x_prime, gamma);
    };

    return trapezoid(s, MIN, MAX, EPS);
}
```

Or you should make templates just like `Compare` or maybe use the class `binary_function`. [See an example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/binary_function).

Comment: Good diagnostic.  But also some luck, because there is no guarantee given on `name()` as explained [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name): a different compiler could produce the same `name()` for different types.  Your demonstration would then be as misleading as the gcc error message.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that each lambda is its own, distinct type, and your function `splot()` requires `g` and `l` to be exactly the same type. If you pass the same lambda to `splot()`, you will notice it will compile fine:

```
cout << "x: " << x << endl << "V(x): " <<
    splot(gauss, gauss, x, sigma, gamma) << endl;
```

But do you need templates at all? You just need to make sure the first two arguments are functions of the required type, *and you know the type already*, so try this instead:

```
double splot(std::function<double(double, double)> g, std::function<double(double, double)> l, double x, double sigma, double gamma) {
    ...
}
```